# Android Parcelable JsonArray in Side JsonObject

Tags: java, android, json, gson, parcelable

When i am trying Parce this json data with GSON. I am unable to get JsonArray in side of JsonObject. Below is my code, every suggestion will get appriciated.

JSON DATA FROM SERVER :

```
{
"GetJobDetails": {
    "MaxAmount": 0,
    "CreatorId": 1,
    "JobImages": [
        {
            "ImagePath": "http://192.168.1.108:8088/Uploads/6e660c0c-4a2b- 42dc-ad97-82cc3efe87a0.jpg",
            "JobImageId": 1
        },
        {
            "ImagePath": "http://192.168.1.108:8088/Uploads/ccf1087d-9f7e-4c21-bc61-8aa3fd924e05.jpg",
            "JobImageId": 2
        },
        {
            "ImagePath": "http://192.168.1.108:8088/Uploads/4333e8b6-0079-457f-a225-fd7900ea81b1.jpg",
            "JobImageId": 3
        }
    ],
  }
 }
```

In ACTIVITY :

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String response = new String(mresponce);
    JobDetails jobDetails= gson.fromJson(response,    JobDetails .class);

    Log.e("JobDetails ",""+jobDetails.getJobImagesList());
```

this log prints allways null even when i have images list there in my data.

MODEL CLASS :

```
public class JobDetails implements Parcelable {

private int MaxAmount;
private int CreatorId;
private List<JobImage> JobImages;

public JobDetails() {

}

public JobDetails(Parcel parcel) {
    this.MaxAmount = parcel.readInt();
    this.CreatorId= parcel.readInt();
    this.JobImages = new ArrayList<JobImage>();
    parcel.readTypedList(JobImages, JobImage.CREATOR);

}

// Parcelable
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.MaxAmount);
    dest.writeInt(this.CreatorId);
    dest.writeList(this.JobImages);
    // TODO: Not Parceling AddressList
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public JobDetails createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new JobDetails(in);
    }
    public JobDetails[] newArray(int size) {
        return new JobDetails[size];
    }
};

public List<JobImage> getJobImagesList() {
    return JobImages;
}

public void setJobImagesList(List<JobImage> jobImages) {
    JobImages = jobImages;
}
public int getMaxAmount() {
    return MaxAmount;
}

public void setMaxAmount(int maxAmount) {
    MaxAmount= maxAmount;
  }
 }
```

ANOTHER MODEL CLASS FOR JOBIMAGE:

```
public class JobImage implements Parcelable {

private String ImagePath;
private int JobImageId;
JobImage(){

}
public JobImage(Parcel in) {
    this.ImagePath = in.readString();
    this.JobImageId = in.readInt();
}
// Parcelable
@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.ImagePath);
    dest.writeInt(this.JobImageId);
    // TODO: Not Parceling AddressList
}
public static final Creator CREATOR = new Creator() {
    public JobImage createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new JobImage(in);
    }
    public JobImage[] newArray(int size) {
        return new JobImage[size];
    }
};

public String getImagePath() {
    return ImagePath;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    ImagePath = imagePath;
}

public int getJobImageId() {
    return JobImageId;
}

 public void setJobImageId(int jobImageId) {
    JobImageId = jobImageId;
 }
 }
```

Please help me to find what i am doing wrong in this :

Comment: What is `GetJobDetails` class?

Comment: Thanks for your response .Edited my post. its JobDetails Bean Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top-level JSON object is not a `JobDetails` object, it is an object that has `JobDetails` member name `GetJobDetails`.  You need to handle this level of your JSON.  You can do it with a custom `TypeAdapter`, or perhaps easier, just make a container object and deserialize it.

```
class JobDetailContainer {
   private JobDetails GetJobDetails;
   public JobDetails getJobDetails() { 
       return GetJobDetails;
   }
}
```

then use --

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String response = new String(mresponce);
GetJobDetails getJobDetails= gson.fromJson(response, GetJobDetails.class);

Log.e("JobDetails ",""+getJobDetails.getJobDetails().getJobImagesList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with @iagreen ...I should handel top level json object too..this is what i have done after doing some R&D

```
  public class GetJobDetails {
            public GetJobDetailsResult getGetJobDetailsResult() {
                return GetJobDetailsResult;
            }
           public void setGetJobDetailsResult(GetJobDetailsResult GetJobDetailsResult) {
                this.GetJobDetailsResult = GetJobDetailsResult;
            }
   }
```

For Inner Json :

```
  public class GetJobDetailsResult {
            private Integer MaxAmount;
            private Integer CreatorTotJobPosted;
            private List<JobImage> JobImages = new ArrayList<JobImage>();
            public Integer getMaxAmount() {
                return MaxAmount;
            }
            public void setMaxAmount(Integer MaxAmount) {
                this.MaxAmount = MaxAmount;
            }
            public Integer getCreatorTotJobPosted() {
                return CreatorTotJobPosted;
            }
            public void setCreatorTotJobPosted(Integer CreatorTotJobPosted) {
                this.CreatorTotJobPosted = CreatorTotJobPosted;
            }
            public List<JobImage> getJobImages() {
                return JobImages;
            }
            public void setJobImages(List<JobImage> JobImages) {
                this.JobImages = JobImages;
            }
        }
```

Finally For To Hold JobImages

```
  public class JobImage {

        private String ImagePath;
        private Integer JobImageId;

        public String getImagePath() {
            return ImagePath;
        }

        public void setImagePath(String ImagePath) {
            this.ImagePath = ImagePath;
        }

        public Integer getJobImageId() {
            return JobImageId;
        }

        public void setJobImageId(Integer JobImageId) {
            this.JobImageId = JobImageId;
        }

    }
```

Final Step :

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String response = new String(jsonObjectresponce.toString());
    GetJobDetails getJobDetails = gson.fromJson(response,    GetJobDetails.class);
    GetJobDetailsResult result = getJobDetails.getGetJobDetailsResult();
    // now result object contains my json data.
```